# How to remove or reduce delay of Windows 10 taskbar tooltips?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I'm using Windows 10, and I often need to hover over taskbar icons to read the tooltip to differentiate between the icons. For example, I have a lot of different Google Chrome profiles.

[image]

I really dislike waiting so long (when my mouse is hovering over an icon) for the tooltip to appear.

**How can I make these tooltips appear instantly?**

P.S. I found a related question [here](https://superuser.com/a/177718/74576), but it only let me remove the delay for taskbar previews (rather than tooltips). I also found a question [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-performance/possible-to-change-tooltips-delay/ec72571c-5bc4-4192-a762-8a1240eaf7b3), but as Magritte points out, there is no correct answer yet.

Comment: I wonder if the setting would be somewhere near `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced` https://superuser.com/a/244028/74576

Comment: This is controlled by the application (in this case Explorer.exe) via TTM_SETDELAYTIME.  I don't think that you can adjust it unless somehow the explorer gets this default from its own custom registry entry.  I hope someone else proves me wrong ;)

Comment: Thanks @Ryan for confirming that other people actually find these tooltips useful, I've only ever met people (working in IT at least) who curse the tooltips and wish they could be removed :)

Comment: @hazymat Thanks. Would you mind upvoting if you like the question?